# I want to dynamically bind tree store into tree panel in ext.js 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, treepanel

I want to bind tree store into tree panel in ext.js 4.2.
My Tree Store:

```
Ext.define('My store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad : true,        
    model: 'ria.model.system.TreeProgram',
    root : {
        text : '1depth',
        expanded : false
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',

        url: '/json/programlist.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'children',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){              
                // some code
            },
            load: function(dataStore, rows, bool) {
                // some code
            }
        }
    }
},
```

well,I will try as below.
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#treePanel')[0].bindStore(me.store);
In here ,'Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#treePanel')[0]' is tree panel.
But then i get error!
Let's know me the method to dynamically bind tree store to tree panel.
Regards.

Comment: You get error - what error, PEBCAK error?

Comment: You're missing `',` at the end of your `model:`... line. Is that typo in the original code, or only an error pasting it here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `reconfigure` function to dynamically bind a store.

> **reconfigure**( [store], [columns] )
>
> Reconfigures the grid or tree with a
>   new store and/or columns. Stores and columns may also be passed as
>   params.

So it should go like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#treePanel')[0].reconfigure(me.store);
```

Comment: thank you, but I have still error! "index of" error!